# pass string through a function in R

Tags: r, function, path

I have the following function:

```
example_Foo <- function( ...,FigureFolder){

  # check what variables are passed through the function  
  v_names <- as.list(match.call())
  variable_list <- v_names[2:(length(v_names)-2)] 

  # create file to store figures
  subDir <- c(paste(FigureFolder,"SavedData",sep = "\\"))

}
```

Obviously this is just the start of the function, but I have already run into some problems. Here, I am trying to define the directory where I eventually want my results to be saved. An example of using the function is:

```
weight <- c(102,20,30,04,022,01,220,10)
height <- c(102,20,30,04,022,01,220,10)

catg <- c(102,20,30,04,022,01,220,10)
catg <- matrix(height,nrow = 2)

FigureFolder <- "C:\\exampleDat"

# this is the function
example_Foo(catg,FigureFolder)
```

This generates the following error:

```
Error in paste(FigureFolder, "SavedData", sep = "\\") : 
  argument "FigureFolder" is missing, with no default
```

which i'm guessing is due to the function not knowing what 'FigureFolder' is, my question is how do I pass this string through the function?

Comment: The thing is that because you have used dots before the argument FigureFolder you have to explicitly named it when you rune your function: example_Foo(catg,FigureFolder=FigureFolder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you do not use a named argument, the `FigureFolder` argument is put into `...`. Just use:

```
example_Foo(catg, FigureFolder = FigureFolder)
```

In addition:

```
example_Foo <- function( ...,FigureFolder){

  # check what variables are passed through the function  
  v_names <- as.list(match.call())
  variable_list <- v_names[2:(length(v_names)-2)] 

  # create file to store figures
  subDir <- c(paste(FigureFolder,"SavedData",sep = "\\"))

}
```

could also be replaced by:

```
example_Foo <- function( ...,FigureFolder){

  # check what variables are passed through the function  
  variable_list = list(...)

  # create file to store figures
  subDir <- c(paste(FigureFolder,"SavedData",sep = "\\"))

}
```

Or even simpler:

```
example_Foo <- function(variable_list, FigureFolder){
  # create file to store figures
  subDir <- c(paste(FigureFolder,"SavedData",sep = "\\"))

}
```

Keeping your code simple makes it easier to read (also for yourself) and easier to use and maintain.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I need the function to allow any number of inputs (e.g. catg, weight, height), therefore I do not want to define catg in example_Foo(catg, FigureFolder = FigureFolder). From what you have said I guess it's easier if I create a list first of the variables I wish to pass through the function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to providea value for FigureFolder, eg

```
example_Foo(catg,FigureFolder="FigureFolder")
```

Comment: She did provide one, but not in the correct way. See my answer.